# My microSD to USB adapter isn't recognized by my computer anymore. It's probably corrupt or something. How can I repair it?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, usb-flash-drive, sd-card, repair

My micro USB adapter is most likely broken. It's no longer recognized as even existing by either my Linux laptop or my Linux desktop, eg. the file `/dev/sda` does not exist. How do I repair this device, or what can I replace it with if it's irreparable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the adapter or SD card is broken.

- Test the SD card in another device, without the adapter (an old phone or something)
- Test the adapter with another SD card.

This will help you work out which bit is broken. Then simply replace the bit which has failed. A quick look online shows that micro SD to USB adapters are available for very cheap.

Edit: Just to note that a lot of SD to USB adapters from my experience only show up once they have an SD card in them. So it might not show up if you are just inserting the adapter.

Comment: thank you. I have confirmed that the micro USB is indeed broken. Is there something more durable/repairable than a microUSB adapter?